# Diffuse map wont bake

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking, baking

Trying to join multiple materials into one map by baking it.
[image]

Every time I try to bake the diffuse map, it just turns out all black.

Other maps baked fine except for the diffuse map. Im confused because there already is an image texture plugged into the base colour of each material so it should bake them properly. Metallic Textures are also unplugged.